# problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

this problem occurred when evaluating settings

**flutter android studio**
[image: problem photo]

**settings.gradle**

```
include ':app'

def localPropertiesFile =  File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
def properties =  Properties()

assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader -> properties.load(reader) }

def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
apply from: "$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be a file called 'local.properties' can you check that it exist?. If not create one and pass this data:

```
sdk.dir=<YOUR_ANDROID_SDK_LOCATION>
flutter.sdk=<YOUR_FLUTTER_SDK_LOCATION>
flutter.buildMode=debug
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1
```

Comment: sdk.dir=/home/webcil/Android/Sdk
flutter.sdk=/home/webcil/snap/flutter/common/flutter
flutter.buildMode=debug
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1

Comment: Can you share settings.gradle as a code view with editing your question?